# Add MySQL database data to a HTML element using ajax/jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a test.html page which has two  and four buttons. When the page loads, i want to retrieve data from mysql database using php and then use ajax to display that in the div. But there are four rows in the table. Also when button 1 is clicked values of row 1 should display, button 2 should display values of row2 ..... How to do it? I dont want to query the database for each button click.

**test.html**

```
  <div id="q1"></div>
  <div id="q2"></div>

<button type="button" data-value="1">1</button>
<button type="button" data-value="2">2</button>
<button type="button" data-value="3">3</button>
```

**test.php**

```
$sql = "SELECT q1, q1 FROM test WHERE test=1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo json_encode($result);
```

**test.js**

```
$().ready(function() {

'use strict';
var testid;
var string = "";    

    $("button").click(function(){
    testid=$(this).data("value");



                             $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    url: 'js/php/testpaper.php',
                                    data: {

                                        testid1: testid
                                    }
                                }).done(function(data) { 

                    });
});
```

Comment: On page load, query and select ALL q1,q2,test from the DB. Put it into an array (ajax with javascript array). then on click, loop that array instead and grab the data

Comment: how to do it. do you have any reference

Comment: make the ajax call to the PHP, run the PHP to get the data, format the data as JSON, return it to the client. On "success" or "done" of the ajax, take the data, make some HTML based on it, add the HTML to the page. Any generic example of ajax/PHP you can find online already should demonstrate the basic process and give you some code you can try out. You seem to have some code above already which partially goes towards your goal. Exactly which part of the process are you struggling with? It's not clear what the specific issue is.

Comment: i dont know how to loop through JSON to get the data and add it to a html element

Comment: well the JSON is just an array or object. Do you know how to write a loop in Javascript? And again you can find lots of examples / tutorials of making HTML elements using Javascript. Did you research anything at all? Try anything? It's a _very_ common task, I would be astonished if you couldn't find anything existing already online which would help you, without us having to repeat it here.